# What limits writing to 2 SSD drives at the same time

Tags: linux, windows, ssd, cpu, io

I'm trying to understand about IO and CPU cores and have gotten myself confused.

Does writing to 2 SSD drives depend on the number of cores? In my mind, if it's a single core process then the limitation will be the CPU. If it's a dual core (or more), then it should be able to write to both.

Please note, this isn't about RAID. This is about 2 applications writing to the same hard drive.

Comment: where do you find that you can't write to 2 SSD drives or more at the same time? Modern systems use DMA for several decades which is independent of the CPU to read/write data, therefore the number of cores in the CPU doesn't relate the the SSD access

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc, actually, it's my own understanding from what I've read, nothing has explicity stated it, but if a single core CPU can only do 1 task a time, then it can only send a command to write one thing/block at a time surely.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are talking about a radid 0.At some level the core number should matter, but what matters the most is sata.With Sata2 you have only 3GB/S as with SATA3 you got 6GB/S, that's relevant.

Anyways, dual core, quad core or even more, what matters is the motherboard and the ssds.